# Dataframe - filter the values of a particular column with isin()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in which I have the column "Bio Location", I would like to filter it so that I only have the locations of my list in which there are names of cities. I have made the following code which works except that I have a problem.

For example, if the location is "Paris France" and I have Paris in my list then it will return the result. However, if I had "France Paris", it would not return "Paris". Do you have a solution? Maybe use regex? Thank u a lot!!!

```py
  df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file, encoding='utf-8', sep=',')
  cities = [Paris, Bruxelles, Madrid]
  values = df[df['Bio Location'].isin(citiesfr)]
  values.to_csv(r'results.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: could you had an example of your expecting output please

Comment: @DataSciRookie I would like to be able to extract the word "Paris" from the sentences "Paris Madrid", "Madrid Paris", "Nord-Pas-de-Calais Paris". But when I use "isin()" I have the impression that it extracts "Paris" only when it is at the beginning of the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want here is `.str.contains()`:

**1.** The DF I used to test:

```
df = {
    'col1':['Paris France','France Paris Test','France Paris','Madrid Spain','Spain Madrid Test','Spain Madrid'] #so tested with 1x at start, 1x in the middle and 1x at the end of a str
              }
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df
```

Result:

| index | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Paris France |
| 1 | France Paris Test |
| 2 | France Paris |
| 3 | Madrid Spain |
| 4 | Spain Madrid Test |
| 5 | Spain Madrid |

**2.** Then applying the code below:

**Updated following comment**
*#so tested with 1x at start, 1x in the middle and 1x at the end of a str*

```
reg = ('Paris|Madrid')
df = df[df.col1.str.contains(reg)]
df
```

Result:

| index | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Paris France |
| 1 | France Paris Test |
| 2 | France Paris |
| 3 | Madrid Spain |
| 4 | Spain Madrid Test |
| 5 | Spain Madrid |

Comment: I think using str.contains should be better

Comment: @Drakax Thank you very much, but I would like to be able to find "Paris" whether it is at the beginning of the string, in the middle or at the end.

Comment: @Evarln So when you wrote this:  "if I had "France Paris", it would not return "Paris"." This is actually your problem, not what you want?

Comment: @Drakax I would like to be able to extract the word "Paris" from the sentences "Paris Madrid", "Madrid Paris", "Nord-Pas-de-Calais Paris". But when I use "isin()" I have the impression that it extracts "Paris" only when it is at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: @Drakax thank you!!! It works the way I wanted it to. However, I don't know how to do it if my list has 7000 city names. I'm not going to do a regex with all the city names, am I?

Comment: @evarln Well, at one point you would need to compare your data to something so I would say yes. But maybe you could consider splitting your main dataframe into smaller ones (continents, countries, regions...) and compare them with their respective town names regex?